# Global variable in React using import not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read somewhere that you can use a singleton style object, set it's value and then import it elsewhere and the value will remain. For example:

storage-util.js

```
const storage = {};
export default storage;
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    storage.token = "1234";
    console.log('set token');
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <NavbarDefault />
      <MainSwitch />
    </div>
  );
```

Pricing.js

```
const Pricing = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(storage.token);
    });
    return (
        <h1 className="heading-text font-weight-bold text-center">
            Pricing
        </h1>
    );
};
```

However I am getting `undefined` when trying to access `storage.token` in `Pricing.js`, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps pricing is getting rendered before App. Try putting a console log in the useEffect of pricing and see which one comes up first

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming you're importing storage into App.js and Pricing.js.)

When the Pricing component first mounts, storage is still undefined. The normal way to deal with that would be to introduce a dependency array to watch in your `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(storage.token);
}, [storage.token]);
```

However, since storage isn't **state**, React won't be able to re-run the `useEffect` when storage changes. You'd be best off setting up storage as a state that you can import.

```
// storage-util.js
export const [storage, setStorage] = useState()

// App.js
setStorage( {token: '1234'} )

// Pricing.js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(storage.token);
}, [storage.token]);
```